# How does temperature affect magnets?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, home-experiment

How does an increase/decrease in temperature affect:

- Strength of the magnet
- Polarity
- Other changes?

I have made some research and I have found that increasing the temperature turns ferromagnetic and antiferromagnetic substances in to paramagnetic. As far as I can understand this happens because electrons giggle with the heat and become free to align in the direction of another magnetic field.

How could I demonstrate this changes trough an experiment?

Comment: Your research probably should be a **comment** not an edit to your post.

Comment: Glad those electrons are having a good time (giggle-jiggle).  There was a demo at the S.F. Exploratorium once which heated a magnet to the Curie temperature, but I've never seen one which demonstrated ferro to para. Maybe if you're lucky you can find the critical mass of iron which your magnet can only hold up when ferro, and drops it when para.

Answer (score -1):

With increasing temperature the magnet would lose "strength". This will happen because the different magnetized domains of the magnet will start to become de-aligned by effect of increased fluctuations of the microscopic magnetic entities induced by the temperaute increase.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlnZKSR73S0) you have a video of minutephysics explaining more in depth your question, and he has other interesting accompanying videos on the subject.

Comment: Telling someone to go watch a youtube video is bad form.